# Explanation for difference between groups of finite set under $+, \times$ operation.

Tags: group-theory

Explanation for difference between groups of finite set under operations:$+,\times$ for prime value of $n$.

All values in the set $\{1,\dots, n-1\}$ are generators of $\lbrace \mathbb{Z}_n, + \rbrace$ for prime $n$.

The order of elements are:

1. Order $=7, 1+1+1+1+1+1+1\equiv 0\pmod 7$
2. Order $=7,2\times 7 = 14\equiv 0\pmod 7$
3. Order $=7,3\times 7 = 21 \equiv 0\pmod 7$
4. Order $=7,4\times 7 = 28 \equiv 0\pmod 7$
5. Order $=7,5\times 7 = 35 \equiv 0\pmod 7$
6. Order $=7,6\times 7 = 42 \equiv 0\pmod 7$

The set of elements generated by each element are:

1. $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,0\}$,
2. $\{2,4,6,1,3,5,0\}$,
3. $\{3,6,2,5,1,4,0\}$,
4. $\{4,1,5,2,6,3,0\}$,
5. $\{5,3,1,6,4,2,0\}$,
6. $\{6,5,4,3,2,1,0\}$,

So, is there only one subgroup = the group $\lbrace \mathbb{Z}_n, + \rbrace$?
But, the ordering of elements corresponding to each are unique, though as a set it doesn't matter.

But, when change the operation to multiplication, then same sized subgroup is not there, for all elements. Though, the multiplicative group has to exclude element $0$, as closure property then is not satisfied.

For the generators of $\lbrace \mathbb{Z}_7, \times \rbrace$ the set of values for elements in the set: $\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$ are:

$1> \{1\}$
$2> \{2,4,1\}$
$3> \{3,2,6,4,5,1\}$
$4> \{4,2,1\}$
$5> \{5,4,6, 2,3,1\}$
$6> \{6,1\}$

The subgroups of $\lbrace \mathbb{Z}_7 \rbrace^{\times}$ are : $\{1\}, 
\{1,6\},\{1,2,4\},\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Also, why it is not necessary in case of latter that for prime $n$, all elements in the set $\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$ are generators?

Say, above only elements $3,5$ are generators.

Similarly, for $\lbrace \mathbb{Z}_{23} \rbrace^{\times}$, the elements $2,3$ are not generators as $|2|=|3|=11, |6|=5$, while $|7|=|5|=23$.

Comment: "All values in the set $\{0,\dots, n-1\}$ are generators of $\lbrace \mathbb{Z}_n, + \rbrace$ for prime $n$": no, $0$ isn't.

Comment: @fitzcarraldo thanks, edited. But, request some source for questions raised there.

Comment: $2^7$ doesn't seem relevant (additive group). Morekver, the set under 4 lacks kf thd element $3$

Comment: @fitzcarraldo confused, as in additive group, it should be $2*7$. Only in multiplicative gr6, $2^7$ is possible. Edited the additive group of residues generated by $4$.

Comment: Yes, as you have done for 3, 4, etc., isn't it? Moreover, you'd need to check that 7 is the *least* factor such that times 7 modulo 7 gives 0.

Comment: @fitzcarraldo Sorry, for typo earlier. gr6 -> group.

Comment: @fitzcarraldo have removed typos of $2^7=128$, sorry couldn't understand at that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here $(\mathbb{Z}_{p}, +) $ is finite cyclic group of order $p$.

Also $0\neq a\in \mathbb{Z}_p$ implies $|a|=p$ (Lagrange's theorem and uniqueness of element of order $1$ in a group).

Hence every non identity elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ are generators.

In case of $U_{p}=\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{\star}=\{1,2,3,\ldots ,p-1\}.$

We have that $(U_p, \times)$ is a group of order $\varphi(p)=p-1$

See the difference, any non-identity element of $U_p$ may not have order $p-1$.

To avoid triviality assume $p>3$ and $\varphi(n)$ is even forall $p>3$. Hence $2\mid\text{ord}(U_p) $. Then by Cauchy's theorem, $U_p$ has an element of order $2$ which can't generate the group $U_p (p>3)$.

Again since $U_p$ is a finite abelian group, for all divisor of $\varphi(p) $, there exists an element of that order. Hence for all elements whose order divide $\varphi(p) $ and less than $\varphi(p) $ doesn't generate $U_p$ (such element exists for $p>3$ as $\varphi(p)$ is composite).

In your example $|U_{23}|=\varphi(23)=22$.

Then elements of order $2$, $11$ are not generators.

Comment: Request explanation for elements$3,6$  too.

Comment: See here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n

Comment: Your reference has heading: Cyclic Groups, which states $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to be cyclic for $n=1,2,4,p^k,2p^k$. But isn't $23$ a prime with $k=1$?

Comment: $\Bbb{Z_n}$ is cyclic for all $n$. Consider the ring $(\Bbb{Z_n}, +, ×) $ the $U(\Bbb{Z_n})=U_n$ is the group of units of the ring. $U_n$ cyclic for $n=2, 4,p^k, 2p^k$ where $p$ is an odd prime. Hence $U_{23}$ is also cyclic.

Comment: Thanks for reminding that are considering set of units. But, am not clear about what cyclic word means  in the set of units $U_n$. Does it mean that all elements in the group $U_n$ are generators? But, is it not obvious from the definition? Is $7,23$ not a prime, i.e. $p^k$, with $p=7,23$ with $k=1$.

Comment: Cyclic means generated by a single element (every non identity need not be generators) .Consider $(\Bbb{Z, +}) $ . It's a cyclic group of infinite order but has only two generators $1$ and $-1$. $U_7$ is cyclic because it has an element of order $\varphi(7) $ .

Comment: So, you mean that set of units under $\times$ has property to generate $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Say, the set of units is $\{3,5\}$ in group $\mathbb{Z_7}$, as complete set  is generated.

Comment: Please point in link given (or, elsewhere), why $\lbrace \mathbb{Z}_p,\times\rbrace, \, p=7,23 $ lacks property of having all elements as units.

Comment: I have already proved it in my answer. $|U_7|=\varphi(7) =6$ and $2|6$ and $U_7$ has an element of order $2$ which is not a generator.

Comment: But, seems need more elaboration. You specified Cauchy's theorem, so request it's link too. Also, you stated $|U_{23}|=22$ , which I assume is when $\lbrace \mathbb{Z}_{23}\rbrace^{\times}$ has all its elements as units. Further, as $2| 22, 11|22$, so these elements are not units, but request similarly for elements : $3,6$.

Comment: I suggest you to read about - order of an element, inverse  of an element, cyclic group, Residue classes , Group of units etc. Compute unit groups of some rings. Then try to find inverse, order etc. You can find many questions In MSE related to unit groups.

Comment: "$2|22$ means $2$ is not unit . " I don't know what have you tried to say.